# How to find the coordinates for a point in a R map or figure

Tags: r, formatting, figure, tmap

I am creating a map using the "tmap" package in R. I want to add a scalebar at a specific spot on the map using `tm_scale_bar(position = c("x", "y"),`. How do I find the coordinates for the point? So far I have been using trial and error which works fine for one figure but will become tiresome when making many figures. I seem to recall a function that interactively returned coordinates based on the position of the cursor over a figure. Any advice would be great!

Comment: I don't know that function, but if it's base graphics then use `locator(1)`; if it is `grid`-based such as `ggplot2` then you can use `ggmap::gglocator(1)`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `tmap` image coordinates are (0,0) for lower left corner and (1,1) for upper right corner of the map area. You can use `right`, `LEFT`, etc direction in `position` vector like `tmap::tm_scale_bar(position = c("RIGHT", "BOTTOM"))`